# PHP mysql to output org chart/tree hierarchy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to output my database record which is

```
UserName     Placement      Position    
Jimmy                       left
JLO          Jimmy          left
Shinobi      JLO            left
trialuser4   JLO            right
donald_duck  trialuser4     left
minnie_mouse donald_duck    left
mickeymouse  donald_duck    right
dr_octopus   mickeymouse    left
dr_cucumber  dr_octopus     left
mr_brown111  dr_octopus     right
```

If my tree start with JLO, I wanna output it like

```
JLO
    Shinobi
    trialuser4
        donald_duck
            minnie_mouse
            mickeymouse
                dr_octopus
                    dr_cucumber
                    mr_brown111
```

But using mysql and php, how do I draw the record and output it just like my jsFiddle html code.

Thanks for helping & enlightening !

Comment: Best place to start is by writing some PHP and some SQL, try it, hone it, smooth it and make it perfect. But above all, try something yourself as **we wont write your code for you**.

Comment: @RiggsFolly , actually I tried to draw left, and right, but I not sure how to do the logic to continously draw branch till it end in a while loop, its not i not trying, I do have some try and error. just that I am lost in the way to make it work

Comment: As they say in examination - _SHOW YOUR WORKINGS_ At least then we get a better idea about what you are trying to do

Comment: what is the `Position` for?

Answer (score 0):

We can first build up a nested array that represent the hierarchy. Then print out the list tags recursively:

```
$rows = array(
    array('UserName' => 'Jimmy', 'Placement' => '', 'Position' => 'left'),
    array('UserName' => 'JLO', 'Placement' => 'Jimmy', 'Position' => 'left'),
    array('UserName' => 'Shinobi', 'Placement' => 'JLO', 'Position' => 'left'),
    array('UserName' => 'trialuser4', 'Placement' => 'JLO', 'Position' => 'right'),
    array('UserName' => 'donald_duck', 'Placement' => 'trialuser4', 'Position' => 'left'),
    array('UserName' => 'minnie_mouse', 'Placement' => 'donald_duck', 'Position' => 'left'),
    array('UserName' => 'mickeymouse', 'Placement' => 'donald_duck', 'Position' => 'right'),
    array('UserName' => 'dr_octopus', 'Placement' => 'mickeymouse', 'Position' => 'left'),
    array('UserName' => 'dr_cucumber', 'Placement' => 'dr_octopus', 'Position' => 'left'),
    array('UserName' => 'mr_brown111', 'Placement' => 'dr_octopus', 'Position' => 'right'),
);

$nested_lists = array();
$user_lists = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $placement = $row['Placement'];
    $user = $row['UserName'];

    if ($placement == '') {
        $nested_lists[$user] = array();
        $user_lists[$user] = &$nested_lists[$user];
    } else {
        $pointer = &$user_lists[$placement];
        $pointer[$user] = array();
        $user_lists[$user] = &$pointer[$user];
    }
}

function build_list($arr)
{
    if (count($arr) == 0) {
        return '';
    }

    $html = "<ul>";
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $html .= "<li>$k" . build_list($v) . "</li>";
    }
    $html .= "</ul>";
    return $html;
}

echo build_list($nested_lists['Jimmy']);
```

prints

- JLO

  - Shinobi
  - trialuser4

    - donald_duck

      - minnie_mouse
      - mickeymouse

        - dr_octopus

          - dr_cucumber
          - mr_brown111